# Can't execute a command

Tags: c#, cmd

I have one dism.exe command that installs IIS on windows server 2008 and I am trying to programatically execute that command.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Installing IIS...");
        if (File.Exists("iis.cmd"))
            File.Delete("iis.cmd");


        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("iis.cmd"))
        { sw.WriteLine(@"START /WAIT DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /FeatureName:IIS-ASP /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET /FeatureName:IIS-BasicAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-CGI /FeatureName:IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-CommonHttpFeatures /FeatureName:IIS-CustomLogging /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /FeatureName:IIS-DigestAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-DirectoryBrowsing /FeatureName:IIS-FTPExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-FTPServer /FeatureName:IIS-FTPSvc /FeatureName:IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics /FeatureName:IIS-HostableWebCore /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionStatic /FeatureName:IIS-HttpErrors /FeatureName:IIS-HttpLogging /FeatureName:IIS-HttpRedirect /FeatureName:IIS-HttpTracing /FeatureName:IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility /FeatureName:IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-IPSecurity /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter /FeatureName:IIS-LegacyScripts /FeatureName:IIS-LegacySnapIn /FeatureName:IIS-LoggingLibraries /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementConsole  /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementScriptingTools /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementService /FeatureName:IIS-Metabase /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-ODBCLogging /FeatureName:IIS-Performance /FeatureName:IIS-RequestFiltering /FeatureName:IIS-RequestMonitor /FeatureName:IIS-Security /FeatureName:IIS-ServerSideIncludes /FeatureName:IIS-StaticContent /FeatureName:IIS-URLAuthorization /FeatureName:IIS-WebDAV /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerManagementTools /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole /FeatureName:IIS-WindowsAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-WMICompatibility /FeatureName:WAS-ConfigurationAPI /FeatureName:WAS-NetFxEnvironment /FeatureName:WAS-ProcessModel /FeatureName:WAS-WindowsActivationService"); }
        File.SetAttributes("iis.cmd", FileAttributes.Hidden);

        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"iis.cmd") 
           { 
              UseShellExecute = false, 
              RedirectStandardOutput = true, 
              RedirectStandardError = true 
           };
        Process pro = Process.Start(psi);
        pro.WaitForExit();

        if (File.Exists("iis.cmd"))
            File.Delete("iis.cmd");

        Console.WriteLine("IIS is installed");
        Console.WriteLine("Exiting...");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

The problem is that this code can not install the IIS. I can see a blank window popup and vanish immediately.
When I manually open the cmd file, the command runs properly, installing IIS.

**EDIT:**
I just tried below change and it still does not work ! All I can see is one blank window (dism.exe) popup and finish in a flash of second.

Comment: I think you are missing the `.Flush()` part. Try adding `sw.Flush()` after `WriteLine`. Maybe I'm just wrong, but give it a try. Is the command right when checking `iis.cmd` manually?

Comment: @Kimmax - yse, you are just wrong - notice `using` in the code.

Comment: I believe this may have something to do with the permissions/privileges of the user. Perhaps you are not running in elevated mode?

Comment: Log output to a file from your CMD... Also it is unclear why you want to use "start" instead of directly calling "dism" (with absolute path) from the CMD  or even directly calling "dism" from C#.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to start `iis.cmd` as if it were an executable file. It is not.

You need to start `cmd.exe`, the command interpreter, and pass it `iis.cmd` as an argument.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C iis.cmd") 
{
    ....
}
```

The `/C` option is to make the interpreter terminate when the script finishes.

If you wanted to be more correct you might choose to read the `COMSPEC` environment variable instead of hard coding `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Isn't a `.cmd` a kind of an executable file? Windows can start them without an cmd when running from Windows + R too?

Comment: @Kimmax A .cmd file has in it whatever you put in it. In this case the asker put text in it. When you ask the shell to open a `.cmd` file by default it associates that with the command interpreter, `cmd.exe`. But the shell does not get a look in here because `UseShellExecute = false`.

Comment: +1. indeed ... OP explicitly specifies false - forgot to scroll code... sorry about that. OP may even rin "dism" directly to make code simpler...

Comment: I just tried that and it still does not work ! All I can see is one blank window (dism.exe) popup and finish in a flash of second.

Comment: So you need do some debugging

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be some issue with path of dism.exe. The below code worked:

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dism.exe"))
    sw.WriteLine(@"START /WAIT C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /FeatureName:IIS-ASP /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET /FeatureName:IIS-BasicAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-CGI /FeatureName:IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-CommonHttpFeatures /FeatureName:IIS-CustomLogging /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /FeatureName:IIS-DigestAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-DirectoryBrowsing /FeatureName:IIS-FTPExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-FTPServer /FeatureName:IIS-FTPSvc /FeatureName:IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics /FeatureName:IIS-HostableWebCore /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionStatic /FeatureName:IIS-HttpErrors /FeatureName:IIS-HttpLogging /FeatureName:IIS-HttpRedirect /FeatureName:IIS-HttpTracing /FeatureName:IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility /FeatureName:IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-IPSecurity /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter /FeatureName:IIS-LegacyScripts /FeatureName:IIS-LegacySnapIn /FeatureName:IIS-LoggingLibraries /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementConsole  /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementScriptingTools /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementService /FeatureName:IIS-Metabase /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-ODBCLogging /FeatureName:IIS-Performance /FeatureName:IIS-RequestFiltering /FeatureName:IIS-RequestMonitor /FeatureName:IIS-Security /FeatureName:IIS-ServerSideIncludes /FeatureName:IIS-StaticContent /FeatureName:IIS-URLAuthorization /FeatureName:IIS-WebDAV /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerManagementTools /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole /FeatureName:IIS-WindowsAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-WMICompatibility /FeatureName:WAS-ConfigurationAPI /FeatureName:WAS-NetFxEnvironment /FeatureName:WAS-ProcessModel /FeatureName:WAS-WindowsActivationService");
else if (File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\System32\dism.exe"))
    sw.WriteLine(@"START /WAIT C:\Windows\System32\dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /FeatureName:IIS-ASP /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET /FeatureName:IIS-BasicAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-CGI /FeatureName:IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-CommonHttpFeatures /FeatureName:IIS-CustomLogging /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /FeatureName:IIS-DigestAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-DirectoryBrowsing /FeatureName:IIS-FTPExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-FTPServer /FeatureName:IIS-FTPSvc /FeatureName:IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics /FeatureName:IIS-HostableWebCore /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionStatic /FeatureName:IIS-HttpErrors /FeatureName:IIS-HttpLogging /FeatureName:IIS-HttpRedirect /FeatureName:IIS-HttpTracing /FeatureName:IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility /FeatureName:IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-IPSecurity /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter /FeatureName:IIS-LegacyScripts /FeatureName:IIS-LegacySnapIn /FeatureName:IIS-LoggingLibraries /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementConsole  /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementScriptingTools /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementService /FeatureName:IIS-Metabase /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-ODBCLogging /FeatureName:IIS-Performance /FeatureName:IIS-RequestFiltering /FeatureName:IIS-RequestMonitor /FeatureName:IIS-Security /FeatureName:IIS-ServerSideIncludes /FeatureName:IIS-StaticContent /FeatureName:IIS-URLAuthorization /FeatureName:IIS-WebDAV /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerManagementTools /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole /FeatureName:IIS-WindowsAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-WMICompatibility /FeatureName:WAS-ConfigurationAPI /FeatureName:WAS-NetFxEnvironment /FeatureName:WAS-ProcessModel /FeatureName:WAS-WindowsActivationService");
```